# Problems listing States on ComboBox (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm having troubles to list Brazillian States (The only States for now) on ComboBox2 
I have one Database with 3 Tables , Paises(Contries), Estados(States) and Cidades(Cities), i'm trying to get the States using the Country Number and list it in the ComboBox2 but it isnt working.

My Code

```
private void Account_Create_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=WINDOWS-PC\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=World;Integrated Security=True");
        string sql = "Select * from Paises";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataReader sdr;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                string Pais = sdr.GetString(1);
                comboBox1.Items.Add(Pais);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=WINDOWS-PC\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=World;Integrated Security=True");
        string sql = "Select Cod from Paises where NomePT = '" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataReader sdr;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                string Cod = sdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                lbl1.Text = Cod;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=WINDOWS-PC\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=World;Integrated Security=True");
        string sql = "select Cod , Estados from Estados where PaisCod = " + lbl1.Text + "";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataReader sdr;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (sdr.Read())
            {          
                string Cod = sdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                lbl2.Text = Cod;

                string Estado = sdr.GetString(1);
                comboBox2.Items.Add(Estado);     
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=WINDOWS-PC\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=World;Integrated Security=True");
        string sql = "Select * from Cidades where Ci_Cod = " + lbl2.Text + "";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataReader sdr;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                string Cidade = sdr.GetString(1);
                comboBox3.Items.Add(Cidade);  
            }
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I'm kinda new with C# and Windows Forms, it's something on my code?

Comment: does the items get added?

Comment: yes, i cheked it multiple times to make sure that it will run fine

Comment: Did you try debugging it? Instead of `comboBox1.Text` I would recommend `comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()` in your SelectedIndexChanged-methods. 
So where exactly does it fail?

Comment: The CheckBox2 doesn't list the States, it should list it by using the number on label1.Text, sending a query to DB `select Cod , Estados from Estados where PaisCod = " + lbl1.Text + "";` .The same thing should work on ComboBox3.

Comment: _but it isnt working_ - there are not enough information to help you, tell us symptoms you get when _it isn't working_? Exceptions thrown, what is exception message?, do states really exists in database? etc?

Comment: that's the deal, it says nothing, any Error Mesage, any Warnings, it just don't list the states, the database is 100% ok, i checked it many times, the CheckBox1 list the Countries, but the CheckBox2 don't.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to make it work.
I can't explain exactly how i make it but that's the code :

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {              
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=WINDOWS-PC\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=World;Integrated Security=True");
        string sql = "Select * from Paises";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataReader sdr;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                string Pais = sdr.GetString(4);
                comboBox1.Items.Add(Pais);
            }                                                                        
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=WINDOWS-PC\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=World;Integrated Security=True");
        string sql = "Select Cod from Paises where Nome = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataReader sdr;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                string PaisCod = sdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                Cod.Text = PaisCod;
            }


            sdr.Close();


            string a = "Select Estados from Estados where PaisCod = " + Cod.Text + "";
            SqlCommand cm1 = new SqlCommand(a , con);
            SqlDataReader sd1;

            sd1 = cm1.ExecuteReader();

            while(sd1.Read())
            {
                string aqw = sd1.GetString(0);
                comboBox2.Items.Add(aqw);
            }

            sd1.Close();     
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=WINDOWS-PC\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=World;Integrated Security=True");
        string b = "Select Cod from Estados where Estados = '" + comboBox2.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(b , con);
        SqlDataReader sdr;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while(sdr.Read())
            {
                string Cod = sdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                Ci_Cod.Text = Cod;
            }

            sdr.Close();

            string c = "Select Cidade from Cidades where Ci_Cod = " + Ci_Cod.Text + "";
            SqlCommand cm1 = new SqlCommand(c , con);
            SqlDataReader sd1;

            sd1 = cm1.ExecuteReader();

            while(sd1.Read())
            {
                string Cidades = sd1.GetString(0);
                comboBox3.Items.Add(Cidades);
            }
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

(Yeh, some of my variables are a mess)
So, basicaly, when the form loads, the Countries table load on CheckBox1. 
When the user select a country on CheckBox the Label Cod recieves the Country Code, after that, the CheckBox2 automaticaly select the States where the "PaisCod" is equal to the Country Code, when the State is selected the Label "Ci_Cod" recieves the State Code, and finally, the CheckBox3 select the Cities that the Code is equal to the City code. Sorry if this is confusing, comment if you don't understand it.